# How to port-forward with ssh using two proxies?

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I am communicating with a remote server through a proxy by creating an SSH tunnel in the following way:

```
ssh -L 7777:remote:9999 user@proxy1
```

then I run my software with: software --port localhost:7777

I need to make the tunneling slightly more complex by using another tunnel from `proxy1` to to another proxy (`proxy2`) and then to `remote`. In other words, I want to change the command to something like this:

```
ssh -L 7777:proxy2:8888 user@proxy1
```

but I am not sure how to configure proxy2 to tunnel everything that comes on port 8888 to remote:9999.

I have root priviledges on both `proxy1` and `proxy2`.